# Incompatible type for NSStringFromSize([self intercellSpacing])?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, imagekit

Something quite strange is happening in my [IKImageBrowserView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html) subclass:

I'm trying to print the size of intercellSpacing and cellSize respectively.

```
CBDebug(@"intercellSpacing %@", NSStringFromSize([self intercellSpacing]));
CBDebug(@"cellSize %@", NSStringFromSize([self cellSize]));
```

The second line is absolutely fine but the first one doesn't compile:

> Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'NSStringFromSize'.

However the two functions are returning the same type:

```
- (NSSize)intercellSpacing
- (NSSize)cellSize
```

The SDK used in xCode are 10.6.
What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Just for kicks, try a `isKindOfClass:` call on them and see if its actually returning an NSSize? Maybe its doing something fishy and returning the same style struct but not an *actual* NSSize.

Comment: @RyanPoolos But NSSize is not an objective-C class. I can't check in that way

Comment: You right lol. Forgot about that small detail lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your deployment target is set to 10.6.

With that setting set to any earlier version, you can't use anything that didn't exist yet on 10.6, which is when `-[IKImageBrowserView intercellSpacing]` was introduced.